# Sentry SDK with Asp.Net 4.6.1 Not working

Tags: asp.net, sentry

I have an Asp.Net app, using .net 4.6.1 version. When I installed Sentry nuget and used Sentry SDK, nothing working, no events are being sent to Sentry. Below is global.asax configs where I tried this Sentry.

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sentry" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sentry.AspNet" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sentry.Extensibility" %>
<script runat="server">
    private IDisposable _sentry;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
       _sentry = SentrySdk.Init(o =>
        {
            o.Dsn = "dsn url";
            
        });

        // Initialize Sentry to capture AppDomain unhandled exceptions and more.
        
    }
    // Global error catcher
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();

        SentrySdk.CaptureException(exception);
    }


    protected void Application_End()
    {
        if (_sentry != null)
            _sentry.Dispose();
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the sample in the documentation [here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnet/#configuring).  Specifically, you need to change your code as follows:

- Add `o.AddAspNet();` to the body of your `SentrySdk.Init` call
- Use `Server.CaptureLastError()` in your `Application_Error` method

If you want to enable Sentry's performance monitoring features, you also need to:

- Set a `TracesSampleRate` in your options
- Add the following code:

  ```cs
  protected void Application_BeginRequest()
  {
      Context.StartSentryTransaction();
  }

  protected void Application_EndRequest()
  {
      Context.FinishSentryTransaction();
  }
  ```